# Not getting any data from console.log in loop method

Tags: angular

I am trying to build up a data set that I can use for my radio button options however I am having difficulty when trying to build up the respective data. I call a service endpoint which gives me 3 objects. In each object there is a value called `restructureAllowed`. If the object has this value set to `Y` then I want to add it into a dataset that I can use for my radio button options. I added comment in the code to explain better

Here is my code

```
getLoanAdjustmentPreValidate() {
this.avafService.GetAVAFPreValidateLoanAdjustment(this.getAVAFPreValidateLoanAdjustmentRequest).subscribe((resp) => {
    //assign resp.loanAdjustmentResult.loanAdjustmentList to this.loanAdjustmentResult
    this.loanAdjustmentResult = resp.loanAdjustmentResult.loanAdjustmentList;
    //loop through this.loanAdjustmentResult to get which objects have restructureAllowed value as Y
    for (let i = 0; i < this.loanAdjustmentResult; i++) {
      //push values to this.loanAdjustmentResult
      if (this.loanAdjustmentResult[i].restructureAllowed == "Y") {
        this.loanAdjustmentResult.push({ "label": this.loanAdjustmentResult[i].restructureType, "checked": false, "name": "reduceoptionRadio" })
        console.log(this.loanAdjustmentResult);
      }
    }

  }, error => {
    ...
  });
}
```

The `resp.loanAdjustmentResult.loanAdjustmentList` value from the service call looks like this

```
[
    {
        "description": "Restructure Option",
        "restructureType": "instalment",
        "restructureAllowed": "Y",
        "reason": null,
        "reasonCode": "0"
    },
    {
        "description": "Restructure Option",
        "restructureType": "term",
        "restructureAllowed": "Y",
        "reason": null,
        "reasonCode": "0"
    },
    {
        "description": "Restructure Option",
        "restructureType": "balloon",
        "restructureAllowed": "Y",
        "reason": null,
        "reasonCode": "0"
    }
]
```

It looks like my codes not even getting to the console log. Any ideas what I can do or if I can make question clearer please let me know.

I added a stackblitz example here. I just hardcode the response in place of the service call
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-starter-hqj3vq?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Assuming that you're actually getting the response, I'm guessing that `this.loanAdjustmentResult` is 0, and that's causing 
`for (let i = 0; i < this.loanAdjustmentResult; i++) ` 
to terminate immediately.

Try logging the value of `this.loanAdjustmentResult` just before the `for` loop.

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek I do see the log just before `this.loanAdjustmentResult = resp.loanAdjustmentResult.loanAdjustmentList;`. I added another log just after `for(let i = 0; i < this.loanAdjustmentResult; i++) {` and I don't see the consol log here

Comment: I updated my comment - take a look

Comment: I see the value of `this.loanAdjustmentResult` just before the for loop. i updated my question with a stackblitz demo. I just hardcoded response in place of service call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had modified the method.Can you try with this?

```
getLoanAdjustmentPreValidate() {
this.avafService.GetAVAFPreValidateLoanAdjustment(this.getAVAFPreValidateLoanAdjustmentRequest).subscribe(resp => {
    //assign resp.loanAdjustmentResult.loanAdjustmentList to this.loanAdjustmentResult
    this.loanAdjustmentResult = resp.loanAdjustmentResult.loanAdjustmentList;
    //loop through this.loanAdjustmentResult to get which objects have restructureAllowed value as Y
    for (let i = 0; i < this.loanAdjustmentResult.length; i++) {
      //push values to this.loanAdjustmentResult
      if (this.loanAdjustmentResult[i].restructureAllowed == "Y") {
        this.loanAdjustmentResult.push({ "label": this.loanAdjustmentResult[i].restructureType, "checked": false, "name": "reduceoptionRadio" })
        console.log(this.loanAdjustmentResult);
      }
    }

  }, error => {
    ...
  });
}
```

Comment: This gives a weird error where you added `(resp: Array<{}>)`. No overload matches this call. I added a stackblitz. I just hardcode the response in place of the service call https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-starter-hqj3vq?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Just replace with resp instead of (resp:Array<{}>) in the method  given above and check one and let me know

Comment: I forgot `.length` on my for loop :(

Comment: Yeah in the method which I gave, .length was mentioned